# HTML and PHP between PHP if Tags

Tags: php, html

Im a beginner in php and want to get help from you guys here,
I have a php include tag which i want it to be between a html tag and both of them between a php if tag ... I have tried this and is giving erro, please help.

```
<?php if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) ?>
<section class="content">
<?php { include '_include-content.php'; } ?>
</section>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: you missing `:` at the end. it should look like: `<?php if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) : ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to
http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

```
<?php if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()): ?>
    <section class="content">
        <?php include '_include-content.php'; ?>
    </section>
<?php endif ?>
```

or

```
<?php if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()){ ?>
    <section class="content">
        <?php include '_include-content.php'; ?>
    </section>
<?php } ?>
```

should work fine..

Comment: I have to wait for a bit, it says i need to :p

Answer (score 2):

Do like this [Enclose any **`HTML`** content inside **`echo`** statement.]

```
<?php 
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) 
{
echo "<section class='content'>";
include '_include-content.php';
echo "</section>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The PHP if function works as follow

```
if (conditions) {
  // do sth
}
```

or

```
if (conditions):
  // do sth
endif;
```

You made a mix using the brackets and endif
so for your Problem, try:

```
<?php if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) { ?>
<section class="content">
<?php include '_include-content.php'; ?>
</section>
<?php } ?>
```

I suggest this syntax because it is normally used.

For your problem, see the note in http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

> Note: Mixing syntaxes in the same control block is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()){ ?>
    <section class="content">
        <?php include '_include-content.php'; ?>
    </section>
<?php } ?>
```